# Find command to search for files

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to know what this command actually does:

```
find $LogPath -name 'c1234.*[0-9]' -ctime +1 -exec compress -f {} \;
```

where `$LogPath` is the current log path, `c1234` is the module name.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? "What does this command do" tends to be too broad of a question. Also, since this seems to be more about command line usage than programming, it's maybe better suited for the [su] or [unix.se] sites.

Comment: [ExplainShell handles this one fairly well](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%24LogPath+-name+%27c1234.*%5B0-9%5D%27+-ctime+%2B1+-exec+compress+-f+%7B%7D+%5C%3B).

Comment: And see ["How does this code work?" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306160/how-does-this-code-works-questions) on [meta], which (along with its linked duplicates) discusses why we generally consider this class of question too broad to be on-topic here, unless narrowed to ask about a very specific *aspect* of the given code, describing which parts you do and don't understand, which research was performed, and what parts of the results of that research turned out to be inconsistent or confusing.

Comment: Hi, find $LogPath -name 'c1234.*[0-9]' -ctime +1  is searching for a file c1234.xxxx(where xxxx can be a numerical value ) which was created 1 hour before. The rest part, -exec compress -f {} \; is confusing as what it does. Is it compressing those files ?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html  it is running the command `compress -f {}` for each found entry. The `{}` is substituted for the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find $LogPath` find all files under $LogPath

`-name 'c1234.*[0-9]'` with a name c1234. followed by a numeric value

`-ctime +1` and whose status was last changed 1 day (or more) ago

`-exec compress -f {} \;` and run compress command on each one of them